# How can I be sure Apple hasn't tampered with my app?

Tags: ios, app-store, reverse-engineering, code-signing, jailbreak

From what I understand, when you upload an iOS app to the App Store and it is approved, Apple has a process where they actually encrypt the app using a key only they have (it is also baked into all Apple devices), then re-sign it (seeing as they don't have the original publisher's private signing key). Hence the actual app that somebody downloads from the App Store no longer contains any cryptographic "proof" that it is the app the publisher sent to them.

Regardless of whether Apple would ever bother taking the risk of modifying an uploaded app (for what gain?), it would seem that as a software publisher it's very difficult, if it not impossible, to be sure that what gets downloaded from the App Store hasn't been tampered with at some point before Apple encrypted/re-signed it.

Yes, it can be installed on a jailbroken device and tools like clutch used to decrypt it again, but there's no simple way to detect whether some modification has been made that I can determine. Ideally I would like to have some sort of runtime check in the app that it is not been tampered with or re-packaged in anyway, but while I can do this for apps not distributed through the app store, it seems it may not be possible for app store apps.

Also, does anyone know if the process is the same for TestFlight apps?

Comment: You cannot be sure, full stop. They could craft and distribute a malicious modification of your app at any time even _after_ any checks you could perform. The only question is: why should they bother with your app when they have the same power at bootloader level?

Comment: You could try online hash check. Before submitting an app, hash its __text section and store on the server. When your submitted app contacts the server it will hash its __text section at runtime and send it to the server. But that gonna work only in case they don't recompile your app, which they can do using bitcode. Same can be done with every other file. That's actually how Apple does their IPA signatures - they hash all files individually and sign the list of the hashes.

Comment: @Siguza, true, though you could reasonably argue that a rogue Apple developer who wanted to take advantage of their control of the platform would be rather more likely to pick on a particular app they thought could be modified for malicious purposes rather than attempt sneaking in a code change to the actual operating system. Though one assumes in either case Apple has strict internal processes that require internal reviews and approvals etc. etc.  It's not something I'm genuinely worried about, more of a theoretical concern.

Answer (score 0):

Thats simply not possible on any non-jailbroken device since you can't access the executable from within the sandbox. In order to check for changes, you would have to escape the sandbox, decrypt the executable and than maybe get the hashsum (sha1,md5...) and compare it to the uploaded version.